# Can't detect \n character in string from post request

Tags: node.js, rsa

[image]I need to post private, public keys (generated with `ursa` package) and file to NodeJs server for signing this file. These keys have format like this:

```
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIICXQIBAAKBgQCt6tv2w4sEuHrvCtIgmajM3Dbf7S0aXdM1aG2kON/uG4ibd7R1\n6o
osp847tXgYYJaOB1lKRRDqUETLg1n6LqMHnzNF1NvC0bEtXym90TIXd2CosmWm\nX/R+52
JdM5vuH5kOMuzmYhBTkd8uJln7P+FbuRe9mikRcNSDD2pWojWF3QIDAQAB\nAoGAXhEUrj
Bvpbr+SwKoSpex1DQbvhwzc/phfZahDtzwSYI87hHd2pVj7OlKQ8NQ\nVKcRZ3qUEfavQn
zt6MF/zjChXl67pEG9P6Jv1EAoZjLXf58w0iTJbLZU12Ds53kl\nI4OxnyOCDmPMQiUuDE
XbiJaornSr8Wve8nGje98Ew/WiC6ECQQDUYyJKyGWJXKby\nTe4jj7Wu184v/kgMgRPeOV
3IQZ3WaZDV10BqHd6Nz8ey9sY9hFJML2naSMNSyDXR\nSV5sn/QZAkEA0aFtOvu7K+TEIW
mT14KLN+53IwZ5TVZFomyogkORDe9Q1reIAzV0\n2pNHXiJqMr/MKlp8RD1AKtiWkl6RC/
L4ZQJBAJHy/eG+DGh0jxT7kKZHX2ajTkGU\n0BYnrWuMqHGxBbIOIUWSAeXqWMHDA0xsYJ
Ztk9Be1LL4RaFhi/oiHQ0wbiECQGPY\nnn08jz7t3FkJv2gjfonqZAZju/0Q/WPKm0xIQF
vBw+AxVHAq0viUs6Zrf+eiIO1/\nYbbi8aA2vykCL9XgKV0CQQCeMDc0AJBunncUSgWDnx
AJgW7Th3ukYpEBrJ5gUOpx\n8HKTaIQRv8KLsOkkBhNc5vndTjNDkhJ/ToSkk3tkU29v\n
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

The problem is that when I post such string to server, server can't detect new line characters and I have error while signing (`No start line detected`).
However, if I paste this line directly in function at server - it's OK. 
So, my client html is:

```
<form id="addFile">
 <div>
   <textarea type="text" id="publicKey" name="publicKey" placeholder="public"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div>
   <textarea type="text" id="privateKey" name="privateKey" placeholder="private"> </textarea>
 </div>
 <div>
   <input type="file" id="document" name="document">
 </div>
 <div>
   <input type="submit" onclick="post()" value="Submit">
 </div>
 </form>

    <script>
      function post() {
        var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('addFile'));
          fetch("http://localhost:3001/postfile", {
            method: "POST",         
            body: form
          });
        }
    </script>
```

I have tried to split this line by `\n` symbol but it doesn't work, I also tried to use `match` method with `\n` and `\n\r` parameters and os.EOL parameter - doesn't work.

Console from Firefox after request says this:

> Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST and
>   enctype=multipart/form-data on the form.  The file will not be sent.
>   index.html
>
> TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
>   [Learn More]

My server side code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto')

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app')));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './documents',
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, (file.originalname).split('.')[0] + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 10000000 }
})

app.post('/postfile', upload.single('document'), (req, res, next) => {
  var publicKey =  req.body.publicKey;
  var privateKey = req.body.privateKey;
  const sign = crypto.createSign("SHA256");
  sign.update('Some data');
  sign.sign(privateKey, "hex"); //Error: no start line
})
```

Comment: I doubt server can detect it, can you show the request on your developers console?

Comment: And please show your server side code, whatever you're using to parse `multipart/form-data` may be trimming line breaks.

Comment: I've updated some info

Comment: This errors from console is nothing to worry about. It says that file won't be sent but actually it is sent well

Comment: you have a tiny little bug caused by  your textarea :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line breaks aren't your problem. Your problem is in the `textarea`, you're posting a private key with a whitespace at the beginning.

```
<textarea> </textarea>
<!--      ^ this bad boy -->
```

When you focus that textarea, and copy paste the key, which most likely is what you're doing. The whitespace won't be removed. Notice that the caret starts at position 1, instead of 0.

```
document.getElementById('privateKey').selectionStart; // 1
```

Besides from removing the whitespace in the textarea

`<textarea><textarea>`

You should probably perform a `.trim` on the server side, to avoid any issue with an user adding whitespaces.

```
const publicKey =  req.body.publicKey.trim();
const privateKey = req.body.privateKey.trim();
```

That specific error occurs, because the key, **must** start with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

**UPDATE**

You're literally pasting a private key with: `\n` (Those are not line breaks, just literals `\\n`, you shouldn't do that, but to fix it:

```
 const privateKey = req.body.privateKey.replace(/\\n/g, '\n').trim();
```

When you post a string in a textarea, containing `\n` it will not be equal to: `\n` in javascript, it will be equal to `\\n`

```js
const text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;

console.log(`${text}: ${text === '\n'}`);
console.log(`${text}: ${text === '\\n'}`);
```

```html
<textarea id="text">\n</textarea>
```

Comment: Actually the same problem (   `var ret = this._handle.sign(toBuf(key), passphrase, rsaPadding
Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
    at Sign.sign (crypto.js:331:26)`

Comment: Are you sure you added `.trim` on the server side? because you may be copying a key with extra whitespaces, and do: `console.log(privateKey);`  and show me the output

Comment: See, i've added console.log picture, and yes - I added trim

Comment: Oh, you're litteraly pasting `\n`, check updated answer in 1 minute.

Comment: After update I have this error `Error: error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line`

Comment: But now I have `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` on the first line and everything else on the others

Comment: Updated, you have a final `\n`, use `.trim` after `.replace`

Comment: Still the same `bad line`. Maybe you paste key to texarea something else? Try to paste key from my post

Comment: That was my bad, te replace wasn't global: `.replace(/\\n/g, '\n').trim()`

Comment: Updated image here

Comment: But depending on your key if it's all in one line, or if you have multiples lines it will still fail, because you will have a mix of `\n` and `\\n`

Comment: It works now, thank you so much) Well, the key is always with multipli lines, It's long, I guess It cannot be in one line anyway

Comment: I mean, a real private key has multiple lines, It cannot be single line, but since you don't have actual line breaks, you have `\\n` if what you were posting, wasn't a single line, you will have mixed `\\n` with `\n` and that won't work with my answer (but that's a really messed up key). For that case you should first remove real line breaks, and then parse `\\n`: `if(key.includes('\\n') key = key.replace(/\n/g, '').replace(/\\n/g, '\n')`